# I can't start Neovim after installation

Tags: linux, fuse

I tried to install Neovim through the appimage file by the official documentation, but there was no FUSE on my system, after installing it I was returned this error:

```
Cannot mount AppImage, please check your FUSE setup.
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option.
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE
for more information
open dir error: No such file or directory
```

I thought that uninstalling the fuse would solve this problem, but on the contrary, it remained.
I'm using WSL with Ubuntu